# How do I modify material-ui-next component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is the main component: [source](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tabs/)

```
class CenteredTabs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0,
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <Tabs
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          centered
        >
          <Tab label="Item One" />
          <Tab label="Item Two" />
          <Tab label="Item Three" />
        </Tabs>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```

My issue is that instead of the `state = {value: 0}` 
I want to use `state = {selectedLanguage: 'All'}` because I'm iterating through `const languages = ['All', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Java', 'CSS', 'Python'];` and I have already this piece of code refractored and working:

```
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Tabs
          value={props.value}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          centered
        >
          {languages.map(lang => {
          return (
            <Tab
              key={lang}
              label={lang}
            />
          )
          })}
        </Tabs>
      </div>
  );
```

Anyway, it still uses state value as a number to work properly. I don't want that. I want my value to be the language that I'm iterating through i.e : "All", "JavaScript" ... etc. How do I refractor this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added languages to state

```
state = {
 value: 0,
 languages: 'All',
};
```

then handler:

```
  handleSelected = (lang) => {
    this.setState({ 
      languages: lang,
    });
```

then passing handler to the component:
`onSelect={this.handleSelected}`

works as expected and now I can handle and use the state of my `languages`.